# Not able to load ESRI ArcGIS JS API Map in React app

Tags: reactjs, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm using React [^17.0.1] and arcgis-js-api [^4.18.1]  for the app,

After 'npm start' I'm receiving the below errors,

The console errors are below,

```
[esri.widgets.Widget] widget-intl:locale-error esri.widgets.Attribution TypeError: t is not a constructor
[esri.widgets.Widget] widget-intl:locale-error esri.widgets.Zoom TypeError: t is not a constructor
index.js:1 [esri.widgets.Widget] widget-intl:locale-error esri.widgets.Popup TypeError: t is not a constructor
[esri.Basemap] #load() Failed to load basemap (title: 'Basemap', id: 'gray-vector') TypeError: t is not a constructor
workerFactory.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is not a function
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoomIn' of null
```

[image: Errors]

The SalesChartCard.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
import ArcGISMap from '@arcgis/core/Map';
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView';
import esriConfig from '@arcgis/core/config';

import '../../assets/css/map.css';

const SalesChartCard = () => {
  esriConfig.assetsPath = '/assets';

  const mapDiv = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapDiv.current) {
      /**
       * Initialize application
       */
      const map = new ArcGISMap({
        basemap: 'gray-vector',
      });

      /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
      const view = new MapView({
        map,
        container: mapDiv.current,
        extent: {
          spatialReference: {
            wkid: 102100,
          },
          xmax: -13581772,
          xmin: -13584170,
          ymax: 4436367,
          ymin: 4435053,
        },
      });
      /* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>Map</CardTitle>
        <div className="mapDiv" ref={mapDiv} />
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default SalesChartCard;
```

I followed below links for development,

1. [jsapi-resources](https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/esm-samples)
2. build with [ES modules](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/)
3. [Link](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript/erros-occurred-while-loading-widgets/m-p/1024690#M71696)

Still I'm getting same console errors.

Kindly look into updated [Git-repo](https://github.com/kishorvalgen/gogo-react) and suggest solution.

Clone the repo and run the app then navigate to the url

```
http://localhost:3000/app/dashboards/default
```

then the application breaks and starts to give errors.

Comment: I would consider asking this question on esri's geonet forum, that community is much more active and knowledgable when it comes to the arcgis js api.  I had a similar problem when trying to use the @arcgis/core package with parcel-bundler...I'm suprised you're having it with CRA (webpack).  Could be a bug with the new @arcgis/core package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading to 4.19. What you are seeing looks like a configuration issue that was changed at 4.19.